# how to completely remove more link in typo3 news subhead

Tags: typo3, tt-news

Does anyone know how I can completely remove the [more] link that appears next to the subheader in tt_news items in typo3?  I've tried the following, but neither removes the anchor tag that is generated:

_LOCAL_LANG.default.more = 
_LOCAL_LANG.default.more >

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In tt_news v3 list view, use

```
plugin.tt_news.displayList.subheader_stdWrap.append >
```

With _LOCAL_LANG you can only override or clear language labels. The tags are generated in the code or templates.